# How can I get Apache HTTP Server 2.2 and IIS 5.1 to both work on my localhost?

Tags: apache, iis, port

I figured the easiest thing to do was to just change the port number that Apache listens to, but I still can't get it to start back up after installing IIS. My IIS currently serves up pages correctly at http://localhost:80. I have several PHP projects, and here are the basics of how ports are configured in my httpd.conf:

```
Listen 81

# Begin listening for virtual hosts.

NameVirtualHost *:81

<VirtualHost *:81>

# virtual.myvirtualdomain.com virtual host.

ServerAdmin webmaster@virtual.myvirtualdomain.com
DocumentRoot "c:/Development/HTTPServer_WWW/virtual.myvirtualdomain.com/www"
ServerName virtual.myvirtualdomain.com
ErrorLog "c:/Development/HTTPServer_WWW/virtual.myvirtualdomain.com/logs/log"

<Directory "c:/Development/HTTPServer_WWW/virtual.myvirtualdomain.com/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Then in my Windows hosts file I have an entry like this:

127.0.0.1 virtual.myvirtualdomain.com

I have several of these virtual domains setup, all running locally for numerous PHP projects I'm working on currently. This was all working correctly on port 80, but then I installed IIS 5.1, and the service no longer starts up. I did some research, and they can't both be running on the same port. I changed it so Apache looks to port 81 now, but it still will not start.

**EDIT:**

So, I uninstalled IIS, and now I can't get Apache HTTP Server to startup at all still. I changed all of the settings back to port 80, and it is still failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did what Haarsma suggested, and it turns out that I had removed a virtual directory, and so Apache couldn't find it (thus not starting). Apparently it had nothing to do with the ports at all, and was my dumb mistake. I reinstalled IIS, changed my config for Apache to listen on port 81, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Stop the service, then run Apache from the command line. It will show you the errors occuring during start up.

Comment: Thank you for this -- it showed me the problem, which led me to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Stop the iis server and see if apache starts.
- In command line, run:

  netstat -ano

this will tell you which process ID runs on which port.

- Disable windows firewall

Comment: Stopped IIS. Apache still will not start (it is installed as a service, but I'm using monitor to try and restart). Disabled Windows firewall. No luck. Ran netstat -ano ... I have no idea what I'm looking at :(

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange! I have IIS 6.0 and Apache 2.2 working together correctly on my Windows Server 2003. IIS on port 80, Apache on port 8081, both services set to run automatically.